# Regex positive match and a negative match in a line

Tags: regex

I want to match all lines where **asp:DropDownList** does not contain a class **selectpicker**

Here's what I have so far:

```
^((\b<asp:DropDownList\b)*(?!selectpicker).)*$
```

My test strings are:

```
<asp:DropDownList class="form selectpicker">
<asp:DropDownList class="selectpicker">
<asp:DropDownList class="form">
<asp:TextBox class="selectpicker">
<asp:TextBox class="form">
```

I only want 3rd item from the list as that is the only DropDownList tag not containing the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^<asp:DropDownList(?!.*class="[^"]*selectpicker[^"]*").*>$
```

It uses negative lookahead to ensure that the quoted string following `class` does not contain `selectpicker`. (That said, in most cases, it would be preferable to use an actual XML parser instead)

https://regex101.com/r/ghhAL0/1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/8291949):

```
<asp:DropDownList (?:(?!class="[^"]*selectpicker[^"]*").)*>
```

It matches anything that does not contain the pattern `class="[^"]*selectpicker[^"]*"`.

[.NET Regex Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Casp%3ADropDownList%20%28%3F%3A%28%3F!class%3D%22%5B%5E%22%5D*selectpicker%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%29.%29*%3E&i=%3Casp%3ADropDownList%20class%3D%22form%20selectpicker%22%3E%0D%0A%3Casp%3ADropDownList%20class%3D%22selectpicker%22%3E%0D%0A%3Casp%3ADropDownList%20class%3D%22form%22%3E%0D%0A%3Casp%3ATextBox%20class%3D%22selectpicker%22%3E%0D%0A%3Casp%3ATextBox%20class%3D%22form%22%3E)